# Cannot redeclare Laravel routes method duplication on phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have my own method in route.php file in Laravel 5.2. It works but when I try to run tests on phpunit this message appear:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getRoutes() (previously declared in C:\(...)\ppm\app\Http\routes.php:55) in C:\(...)\ppm\app\Http\routes.php on line 76
```

My routes.php: [here](http://pastebin.com/MJraCWB7)
My UserTest.php: [here](http://pastebin.com/gNcpMTe5)

Comment: Can We see your Test Class?

Comment: @JordanPlamondon yes, I edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2, changing `require` to `require_once` in `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvide.php` fixed the problem.

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
     $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
         require_once app_path('Http/routes.php');
     });
}
```

Comment: But now my tests shows: A request to [http://localhost] failed. Received status code [404].

Comment: I think that is because there is no route for "/" as a guest. Try changing $this->visit("/") by $this->visit("/login") maybe?

Comment: The stack trace says: "A request to [http://localhost/login] failed". Is your root path really on http://localhost ? I think that you miss to put the full path on the visit() function. Exemple: http://localhost/TestProject/login will be $this->visit('/TestProject/login')

Comment: This same. I ran my server by php artisan serve command (and I visit my site at http://localhost:8000)

Comment: localhost:8000 failed at example tests ExampleTest::testBasicExample. http://localhost:8000 pass through ExampleTest and still failing in UserTest

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. I fixed it by assigning a `closure` to a variable. Something like this:

```
$getRoutes = function(){
    Route::get(...);
    // ...
}


Route::group(["middleware" => ["auth"]], $getRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

i get the same problem,i fixed by use function_exists(),like

```
if (!function_exists('getRoutes')) {
  function getRoutes($modules)
  {
      foreach ($modules as $module) {
          $actions = $module->getActions();
          $route = $module->getRoute();

          Route::get("/" . str_plural($route), ["as" => str_plural($route), "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getList"]);
          Route::get("/" . $route . "/find/{search_phrase?}", ["as" => $route . ".search", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getSearchJSON"]);

          if ($actions["add"]) {
              Route::get("/" . $route . "/create", ["as" => $route . ".create", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getAddForm"]);
              Route::post("/" . $route . "/create", ["as" => $route . ".store", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getAddRequest"]);
          }
          if ($actions["edit"]) {
              Route::get("/" . $route . "/edit/{id}", ["as" => $route . ".edit", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getEditForm"]);
              Route::post("/" . $route . "/edit/{id}", ["as" => $route . ".update", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@getEditRequest"]);
          }

          if ($actions["delete"]) {
              Route::delete("/" . $route . "/delete/{id}", ["as" => $route . ".delete", "uses" => ucfirst($route) . "Controller@postDelete"]);
          }
      }
  }
}
```